# How can I generate, compile and apply migrations at runtime for tests in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-assembly, entity-framework-migrations

How can I generate, compile and apply migrations at runtime for tests in C#?

I think I am very close to getting an answer to my question. I was able to generate and compile the migrations, but I was not able to apply them. And searching on the internet for two days gave no results. So, could someone help me figure it out, please?

Here is the code I use to generate and compile my migrations:

```
using (var scope = testServer.Host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = (MyDbContext)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext));

    var migrationsDirName = "Migrations";
    var migrationsAssemblyName = "My.Migrations";
    var sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    var migrationsAssemblyPath = $"{migrationsDirName}{sep}{migrationsAssemblyName}.dll";

    //prepare a directory
    Directory.CreateDirectory(migrationsDirName);
    Directory.GetFiles(migrationsDirName).ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);

    //generate the migration files
    var designTimeServices = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IHistoryRepository>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IMigrationsIdGenerator>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.Model)
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IDatabaseProvider>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IRelationalTypeMappingSource>())
        .AddSingleton(dbContext.GetService<IMigrator>())
        .AddSingleton<IOperationReporter>(new OperationReporter(null))
        .AddSingleton<MigrationsCodeGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<ICSharpHelper, CSharpHelper>()
        .AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationOperationGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<ICSharpMigrationOperationGenerator, CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator>()
        .AddSingleton<CSharpSnapshotGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<ICSharpSnapshotGenerator, CSharpSnapshotGenerator>()
        .AddSingleton<CSharpMigrationsGeneratorDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<IMigrationsCodeGenerator, CSharpMigrationsGenerator>()
        .AddSingleton<MigrationsScaffolderDependencies>()
        .AddSingleton<MigrationsScaffolder>()
        .AddSingleton<ISnapshotModelProcessor, SnapshotModelProcessor>()
        .AddSingleton<IMigrationsCodeGeneratorSelector, MigrationsCodeGeneratorSelector>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
    var scaffolder = designTimeServices.GetRequiredService<MigrationsScaffolder>();
    var migration = scaffolder.ScaffoldMigration("MyMigration", "My.Data");

    var migrationFileName = $"{migrationsDirName}{sep}{migration.MigrationId}{migration.FileExtension}";
    var designerFileNmae = $"{migrationsDirName}{sep}{migration.MigrationId}.Designer{migration.FileExtension}";
    var snapshotFileName = $"{migrationsDirName}{sep}{migration.SnapshotName}{migration.FileExtension}";
    File.WriteAllText(migrationFileName, migration.MigrationCode);
    File.WriteAllText(designerFileNmae, migration.MetadataCode);
    File.WriteAllText(snapshotFileName, migration.SnapshotCode);

    //compile the migration files
    using (var migrationStream = File.OpenRead(migrationFileName))
    using (var designerStream = File.OpenRead(designerFileNmae))
    using (var snapshotStreamStream = File.OpenRead(snapshotFileName))
    {
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation
            .Create(migrationsAssemblyName)
            .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
            .AddReferences(new[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MigrationBuilder).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(BaseScenario).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ModelBuilder).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Action).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Runtime.AssemblyTargetedPatchBandAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.GetName().Name == "netstandard").Single().Location
                )
            })
            .AddSyntaxTrees(new[] 
            {
                CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(migrationStream), path: migrationFileName),
                CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(designerStream), path: designerFileNmae),
                CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(snapshotStreamStream), path: snapshotFileName)
            });
        var result = compilation.Emit(migrationsAssemblyPath);
        TestMyDbContext.MigrationAssembly = migrationsAssemblyPath;
    }

    //apply the compiled migration to the database
    dbContext = (MyDbContext)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext));
    dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Here is my `TestMyDbContext` class:

```
public class TestMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    public static string MigrationAssembly { get; set; } = null;

    public TestMyDbContext(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {

    }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options
            .UseSqlite("Data Source=Data/my.db", c =>
            {
                if(MigrationAssembly != null)
                {
                    c.MigrationsAssembly(MigrationAssembly);
                }
            })
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
    }
}
```

As I was able to find out during my research on the runtime migration generation the `DbContext` instance is necessary to generate the migrations. But also, the migrations assembly is setup during the `DbContext` instance creation in the `OnConfiguring` method.

So, I have the following expectations from the code above: I create the first `DbContext` instance and use it to get the migrations assembly. After that I create another `DbContext` instance, but this time during the creation I can grab the migrations assembly and so, the code on the newly created `DbContext` instance should apply the compiled migrations:

```
dbContext = (MyDbContext)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext));
dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

But that is not happening and the database is not updated by the migration. What may I be missing here?

**UPDATE**

I just have noticed an interesting thing. I downloaded the [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and checked the `my.db` file. It does not get the migration applied. So, I decided to check my migrations `.dll`. I just copied it over to bin (after it was generated at runtime) and commented out the part of code which creates the migrations assembly (i.e. from the `var migrationsDirName = "Migrations";` line to the `//apply the compiled migration to the database` line) and hardcoded the `TestMyDbContext.MigrationAssembly` to be the `.dll` name. And now the migration is applied as expected. But that is not what I am looking for, because I do not want to have to move the migrations `.dll` manually and rerun tests every time there is a change in data model. In a nutshell I was able to apply the migration, but not able to generate and compile it in this way.